# Positional Parameters in C-shell

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I am unable to print positional parameters using this shell command: `echo $1`.

I am using it as following two commands:

```
% set hi how are you
% echo $1
```

Nothing get out of the command, but `hi` should be print.

Comment: What you're doing here is setting 4 variables to empty strings: `hi`, `how`, `are`, and `you`.

Comment: I am trying to set positional parameter 1 = hi, 2= how, 3=are, 4=you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In csh, you need to assign to the `argv` array:

```
> set argv=(hi how are you)
> echo $1
hi
```

**Explanation:**

`argv` is an array variable which contains the command line argument list (the 0th argument is name as the shell was invoked and the other start from 1th index). Variables `$0` - `$n` also contain values of the arguments . So `$argv[1]` is the same as `$1`. To assign to an array variable, you can use either `set arr=(value1 value2)` or `set arr[1] = value1`.

`set value1 value2` would work in `bash`, but `csh` is meant to be similar to the C language, therefore the `argv` array is used (read a little about C program command line arguments if you don't know why).

But in `csh`, this: `set first second` means assigning an empty (null) value to the variables `first` and `second`.

Comment: Thanks Mike!! It worked. Can you please explain why so in csh?

Comment: @Jeetesh I added some explanation.